# Ajax form as partial view? Or maybe pass just data in json?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a best-fit solution for my task.

I have a grid where I display data rows.

I decided that data for specific row will be updated with ajax and a popup modal form.

But I can't decide if my ajax should return a partial view of my form with filled data, or should it return just json and inject the data values into an existing (hidden) popup form.

- With json there is less data to send (instead of full form html
  markup - just data), but I need to manually inject data into form. I
  need to "prepare the form" in javascript.
- With partial view I have full server support in displaying the form
  (I mean razor), I can write complex conditions with more ease, but
  there is an server overhead, because it needs to compute the view
  each time.

Let's face a simple problem: form inputs are visible conditionally depending on a user role. With ajax returning partial view (form) it's quite easy. I think writing this in js might be quite error prone.

Any help regarding this issue appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's really up to you and how you want to handle it.

- If you use JSON, then you're left with a dormant popup or template sitting in your code base awaiting live data to populate it. However, you do have full control over how the form is processed on continuation/exit.
- If you return a view, you can use razor to populate it and keep the UI in the corresponding `~/Views` directory. However, you're now keeping code in the view and not on the page which may make for some "hacking" to make the work-flow operate within the context of the calling page.

Another option may be to use something like handlebars or knockoutjs (depending on how intricate you want to get things). But based on what you've mentioned, it's probably just as easy to keep everything on page and use a JSON helper in the background to feed/save the information.